# It was Lily this and Lily that

Tags: meaning

The following sentences are taken from *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*.
What would you paraphrase the sentence "It was Lily this and Lily that"?

> I was the only one who saw her (= Lily) for what she was－a freak!   But for my mother and father, oh no, **it was Lily this and Lily that**, they were proud of having a witch in the family!

Comment: Why would we paraphrase it? What don't you understand?

Comment: The point is, the parents speak all too many sentences with "Lily" as the subject, indicating an obsession with her. Now I *think* the prototype for this formula exists in a poem, perhaps by Kipling, but I cannot place it offhand and it is hard to search for.

Comment: The poem is [Tommy](http://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/tommy.html), but the meaning's different...

Answer (score 3):

I might paraphrase it as something like "...oh no, **they couldn't get enough of Lily**..."

A more literal sense of "[x] this and [x] that" is that they kept returning to the subject, like they were unable to talk about anything but Lily. It tends to imply that the speaker dislikes talking about the subject, or is at least much less excited about doing so.

In context, she is expressing her jealousy at feeling like Lily was the only child that their parents talked about, and that she felt inadequate because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it was ALL about Lily, suggesting that she was all the characters mother and father talked about.